# What does "g" abbreviate in the standard definition of a public goods game?

Tags: game-theory

The standard definition of a public goods game is
$$\pi_i=E-g_i+x\sum_{i=1}^{n}g_i$$
where $\pi$ stands for **p**rofit and $E$ stands for **e**ndowment. "g" of course stands for the contribution to the public good, but does it really simply abbreviate "good"?

Comment: Should it be $\pi_i$ on the left because the right depends on $i$?

Comment: Yes, thank you @RossMilikan

Answer (score 1):

$g_i$ stands for the (monetary) contribution of individual $i$ to the public good.